# Spring Batch configuration exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have next spring batch configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(Step step1) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1)
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I start my application I receive next exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65a19538
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14f7a80d.jobRepository()
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14f7a80d.CGLIB$jobBuilders$6()
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14f7a80d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c6b630d7.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14f7a80d.jobBuilders()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)

In pom.xml I have next dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any JpaRepositoryFactoryBean variable anywhere in your code? If you do, please post that line.

Comment: No, I don't have such variable.

Comment: Sorry I was inattentive. I found JobRepository interface which extend JpaRepository (SpringData). So I rename JobRepository and everything becomes okay. Please answer on my question and I'll close my post.

Comment: I was hoping that you will find something, otherwise this would have been a huge mistery for a long time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JobRepository instance needs to be renamed, otherwise Spring context will find incorrect candidates for autowiring.

Comment: This is amazing. I had the similar issue and I also able to solved by renaming JobRepository. Thanks guys.

Comment: @GergelyBasco Would be good if you can elaborate on how to rename the `JobRepository` instance..

Comment: @Jimmycan you guide how you have renamed JobRepository

Comment: I see no reference to JobRepository instance so where did you rename it and rename to what?