# ClassCastException is caused by casting JobRepositoryFactoryBean to JobRepository when Spring boot starts a batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]:
>   Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>
> org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9
>
> cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>         ... 18 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9641e37a.jobRepository()
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:59)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9641e37a.CGLIB$jobBuilders$8()
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9641e37a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$19e6f1ca.invoke()
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9641e37a.jobBuilders()

---

Trying to run a batch job using Spring Boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = {BatchJobConfig.class, AJobConfig.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/batch-context.xml")
public class MyApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    }

}
```

Tried to make AJobConfig is subclass of DefaultBatchConfigurer, but it doesn't really work. 
somehow, this error occurs regardless if adding @EnableBatchProcessing or not. 
Tried to add @EnableBatchProcessing to MyApp.java and AJobConfig.java.

I will appreciate if anyone can help point out if I have missed out something obviously?

I am using Spring boot 2.1.8, Spring batch 4.1.2, Spring 5.1.6

---

```
@Configuration
public class BatchJobConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public JobExecutionListener myJobListener() {
        return new MyJobExecutionListener();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class MyJobConfig extends MyAbstractJobConfig {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public String jobName() {
        return "MYJOB";
    }

    @Bean("MYJOB")
    public Job myJob() {
        return newJobBuilder() //
                .next(parms01Step())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean("PARMS01")
    public Step parms01Step() {
        return newStepBuilder("PARMS01") //
                .execute(Cblparmc.class, "zzzzz") //
                .build();
    }
}
```

The batch-context.xml does nothing but defined a place holder

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/my-batch*.properties"/>
```

In AbstractMyJobConfig, there are auto-wired beans, but nothing else is special

```
@Autowired
protected JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
protected StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
```

Comment: please share the code of `BatchJobConfig` and `AJobConfig`

Comment: I have attached the 2 simple configuration beans and described what is in xml content.

Comment: it might be something to do with dependencies in pom.xml. The same configuration can be run in one project, but then have described error in another. Possibly maven dependencies triggered some process in Spring boot configuration.     Moving configuration from src/test to src/main results in error of finding DataSource.

Comment: when moving to main/java, db dependencies must be provided or it will result in error of finding data source. this is resolved by adding HSQLDB driver to classpath as compile scope instead of test.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what caused the problem after having read a couple of times of the link below. 
[Spring Batch configuration exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103284/spring-batch-configuration-exception?rq=1)

The problem is that there is a named as jobRepository in an xml bean definition (batch:job-repository). With @EnableBatchProcessing, I believe this is not required. Besides, this may cause problem with Spring boot auto-configuration?

Removing the bean definition will get the described problem resolved.